# Angular js: Iterate over list in view (ng-foreach)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting json data in server response and return that to $scope.questions

I want to access this questions data in step1.html file.

app.js

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router","ngResource"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("step1", {
              url : "/",
              templateUrl : "easyquote/step1.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            })  
            .state("step2", {
              url : "/step2",
              templateUrl : "easyquote/step2.html",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            })
    }]
    );
}());
```

autoQuoteCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("autoQuote")
    .controller("questionsCtrl",["$scope","$http","$state",questionsCtrl]);

    function questionsCtrl($scope,$http,$state) {
        $http.get('rc1/getQuestions/' + $state.current.name)
             .then(function(response) {
                $scope.questions = response.data;
        });   
    }
}());
```

step1.html

```
    <div ng-controller="autoQuoteCtrl">
        <form name="DTOstep1" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
      <label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
      <br><br>

            <table ng-repeat="questions in que">
                <tr>
                <td>{{que.QuestionData._attributeName}}</td>
                <td></td>
                <tr>
            </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of ng-repeat is the wrong way round. It should be like this:

```
<table ng-repeat="que in questions">
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<table ng-repeat="questions in que">
        <tr>
           <td>{{questions._any_name}}</td>
           <td></td>
        <tr>
     </table>
```